# We're getting complaints about order confirmation emails. Should we make them opt-in?

Tags: e-commerce, email, ordering

This is a weird issue. I think it has to do with user experience, but let me know if I should post it on another SE site.

One one hand, we have many customers who tell us they didn't receive their order confirmation e-mail. We ask them to check the Spam folder, and most of the time it's there, of course.

On the other hand, we have customers who specifically complain about our order confirmation emails. I know it because we use Amazon SES which always sends us a copy of complaints it receives.

Here's what the order confirmation looks like:

[image: example]

Of course the information has been edited out, but otherwise this is exactly what they receive: light text, to the point, no upsell, no marketing. It even has an unsubscribe link, although the email is transactional and therefore exempt.

[I can't find anyone talking about an issue like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=complaints+about+order+confirmation). But still, enough people complain about our emails for our sender reputation to be affected, and for me to be concerned about this

From the user experience standpoint, do you think making the order confirmation emails opt-in is a good idea? This way they will get an e-mail only if they specifically request it on the payment success page.

It sounds like it could work, but I have never heard or seen of anyone do this.

Comment: Is it possible that customers receive multiple order confirmations?

Comment: What are users complaining about, exactly? Is it something about the email, or just the fact that they received one?

Comment: Not that this is *very* likely to be the issue, but I think an unsubscribe link on an email that isn't affected by it is a mistake. It would frustrate me if I clicked that button and then got another of the same type of email. Instead, use "manage subscription preferences", and have that take them to a page where they can check/uncheck email categories, but with "account and order emails" permanently checked. That has been my favourite way that I've seen for companies to give me control but also communicate why I still get emails from them.

Comment: @Levano good point, but it's very unlikely. No such logic in our code. As for rogue duplicates, AWS doesn't seem to log every sent e-mail for me to look at, but I checked account metrics and at the night hours we very often have 1 email per hour. Would have been 2 if we sent out duplicates.

Comment: @Izquierdo Amazon only notifies us that there is a complaint. We get the original e-mail headers & identifiers, and the complaint timestamp.

Comment: @LukeSawczak thank you for sharing the idea, I agree it's a good way to do this, and I'd eventually want our UI to be like that. But I feel like it's very elaborate to actually be the reason for this exact issue. I feel It's more like some people think the Delete and the Spam buttons are interchangeable.

Comment: I'm not sure why users are complaining, but you should NEVER stop order confirmation mails. It's a legal receipt and a way for users to acknowledge confirmation outside of the system

Answer (score 4):

First of all does your brand has a voice? If it does, it is strongly recommended to visualize brand color inside an email to make it easily understandable for user that this is the brand that user has bought items from.

"A brand’s colors and design evoke emotions and a sense of relatability. Some brands, like Nike and Adidas, use templates with very little text in their email campaigns. The heart of effective marketing is color and design. Color accounts for between 62 and 90% of the impression your product creates." ([Sauce](https://westfield-creative.com/blog/should-color-and-design-be-used-in-emails/))

Regarding order confirmation emails I'd suggest you adding a opt-in for user to choose whether to get confirmation email or not. It is worth mentioning the importance of email confirmations, as [64% of consumers believe purchase confirmations are the most valuable messages in their email inbox.](https://www.unific.com/blog/ctr-open-rates-order-confirmation-emails) This is why I'd recommend you that by default user should get an email confirmation. Just because OP isn't sure why exactly users are disappointed, I'd also recommend you looking into other methods of displaying order confirmation information. Maybe a good idea would be to allow user to download a PDF order confirmation?

[image: View order confirmation as PDF]

**EDIT**: User @Devin made a good point by explaining the importance of order confirmation email through legal view. For example in Germany [it is mandatory to provide client with electronic form of order confirmation](https://marketpress.com/documentation/german-market/bestelleingangsbestaetigung/). Before you stop sending order confirmation emails, I recommend you to check if you aren't disobeying the law in the country your business is in. Also the order confirmation as a contract binding works both ways. It means that sending an email with order confirmation provides both the client and the business with a written proof that all the things are in order.

Comment: I think the first point doesn't apply in this case, because it's about advertising emails (in that case strong branding makes sense).

Comment: I think that it was worth mentioning because there isn't enough information regarding users complaints -- an email without visual identity might look sketchy at a first glance and hopefully representing brand colors inside an email would solve this problem. But probably my opinion requires an additional research to be made. :)